# Question about using package babyloniannum

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to use package babyloniannum, here's my file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,babyloniannum}

\begin{document}

\babylonianfont{Santakku}
\babyloniannum{8}

\end{document}
```

I am getting the message that `\babyloniannum{8}` is an undefined control sequence...but no objection to the `\babylonianfont` command. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have the Santakku TrueType font installed? You can download them from http://www.hethport.uni-wuerzburg.de/cuneifont/